# Missing X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest (causes 200 OK But Shows as Error?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, http-headers

When I retrieve data from my localhost as JSON everything is OK. When I try to get that JSON data from a remote machine everything is OK too. I can parse that JSON data comes from my localhost into objects( a datagrid plugin: jqgrid renders it). However when I try to use remote source it doesn't. At firebug it says 200 OK but it shows an error icon and writes it red. I checked the differences between my localhost and remote connection headers and I found that there is not that header at remote connection:

```
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

I think problem may be that. I wasn't setting it and it was working well. It occurs at remote request.

Any ideas to solve it?

**PS:** I tried setting Ajax headers but didn't work:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
    });

    $("#userTable").jqGrid({
        url:'http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8080/aa/bb/cc/user',
        colNames:['User Name','Password'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'userName',index:'userName', width:100},
            {name:'password',index:'password', width:55}
        ],
        jsonReader: ...
        ...
    });
```

When I use that setup I can not even see the GET Request from Firebug.

**PS:** I use Spring 3 with REST and Tomcat as web server.

Comment: Look at [here](http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/) if you need implement JSONP in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have the [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issue. The problem can be solved if the server set some [additional options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_response_headers) in the HTTP header of the response. So the solution is not in the modifying of the client code like you do currently, but in the server code.

I recommend you examine the HTTP options which will be set in the HTTP header by `tables.googlelabs.com` used in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/google-tables3.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317646/jqgrid-returns-blank-cells/4326986#4326986). You will see that the server response has the following additional HTTP options:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

and the JSON response will be placed inside of the call of the function defined by `jsonCallback` parameter. If you would use `jsonCallback=?` jqGrid will generate the name of the function (something like `jQuery16407707202236448429_1319101394784`). You can read more about `X-XSS-Protection` option [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/01/ie8-security-part-iv-the-xss-filter.aspx) and about `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` option [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx).

How you can see in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/google-tables3.htm), the data will be displayed in the jqGrid, so the Cross-site scripting can be implemented in the jqGrid.

Because we call the server `tables.googlelabs.com`, which not support jqGrid paging and sorting parameters, I used in the demo

```
url: 'http://tables.googlelabs.com/api/query?jsonCallback=?',
postData: "sql=" + encodeURIComponent("SELECT * FROM 333136 LIMIT 10")
```

The usage of string instead of object as the `postData` value will *overwrite* any other jqGrid parameters which are typically posted. In you case it will be not needed to do this and probably you need just use `url: 'http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8080/aa/bb/cc/user?jsonCallback=?'`.

In any way you need implement support of JSONP on your server. It means just that the server should "understand" `jsonCallback` parameter. The implementation depends on your server side implementation. It could be just `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"` binding setting for the `webHttpBinding` in case of WCF service (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192132/wcf-service-with-jsonp-over-ssl/5192204#5192204) an example of the `web.config`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022878/posting-cross-domain-json-to-asp-net-with-jquery/2023485#2023485) and [this one](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795201/asp-net-mvc-3-jsonp-does-this-work-with-jsonvalueproviderfactory/4797071#4797071)) additionally for ASP.NET Web services and ASP.NET MVC.