# Yii2 isAjax returns false

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

Run into an issue when trying to run some code(it worked in the past).

I'm using AJAX to run some code, but it returned a 500 error.

Found a couple of the same issue posts and there solutions but, I have tried them all and it will still not work.

It will run the php file so this is not the problem.

[Yii2: isAjax returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177008/yii2-isajax-returns-false)

[Cross-Domain AJAX doesn't send X-Requested-With header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163703/cross-domain-ajax-doesnt-send-x-requested-with-header)

```
id = 'some-data-comes-here';

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
    url: 'delete-image',
    data: {
        id: 'some-data-comes-here';
    },
    success:function(data){           
      $.pjax.reload({ container: '#pjax-product-images' });
    }
});
```

(part of a php class)

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    // all code here
}
```

Comment: It does not **return false**. As you said, there's **code 500**, which means there's exception.

Comment: 500 errors are server errors. They have nothing to do with your JavaScript. Check your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

first check url that you request is exist or not. if exist then there may be any error in that url.

some time this may also arise for cross-plateform issues.
place this code at the start of the controller that may help you.

> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");